# Openshift local (CRC) running error on windows stating Host File Not Writeable

Tags: kubernetes, containers, openshift, redhat

I'm just trying to run Openshift local but I get the following error message:
"Error running post start: host file not writable, try running with elevated privileges"
The full output from the Powershell is as follows:

```html
PS F:\Program Files\Red Hat OpenShift Local> crc start -p ..\pull-secret
WARN A new version (2.19.0) has been published on https://developers.redhat.com/content-gateway/file/pub/openshift-v4/clients/crc/2.19.0/crc-windows-installer.zip
INFO Checking if running in a shell with administrator rights
INFO Checking Windows release
INFO Checking Windows edition
INFO Checking if Hyper-V is installed and operational
INFO Checking if Hyper-V service is enabled
INFO Checking if crc-users group exists
INFO Checking if current user is in crc-users and Hyper-V admins group
INFO Checking if vsock is correctly configured
INFO Checking if the daemon task is installed
INFO Checking if the daemon task is running
INFO Checking admin helper service is running
INFO Loading bundle: crc_hyperv_4.12.13_amd64...
INFO Starting CRC VM for openshift 4.12.13...
INFO CRC instance is running with IP 127.0.0.1
INFO CRC VM is running
Error running post start: host file not writable, try running with elevated privileges
```

I'm running CRC on my Windows 11 Enterprise. I thought that it had something to do with Windows Host file located at /system32/drivers/etc, so I granted full control permission to all users on my PC over the Hosts file, then stopped and started again the CRC but got the same error. Any idea?